What did a colour mixer do in 1830 in Manchester?
My great great grandfather lived in Salford, Manchester. In 1833 his marriage certificate indicated his profession as colour mixer. I believe this involved work in textile- finishing/ printing but have been unable to find any details to support that.

I found two very similar occupation terms:

Colour Man: mixed coloured dyes for use on textiles. The term may also refer to an assistant to a House Painter.
Colourator: person who worked with coloured dyes. The US spelling is of course Colorator.

This would seem to at least support your theory about the textile industry.
The above definitions were obtained from Family Tree Researcher website but can be found on other websites as well.

My initial thought was mixing paints for 'Floor Cloth'.  But then I thought Manchester was an area with a lot of Cotton Mills.  So its even more likely to be mixing the dyes for the cotton industry.
The earlier answer makes me think my first idea is the best answer.
